# Do comprehensions have the same asymptotic complexity as explicit for cycles?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, complexity-theory

In most cases using list/dict comprehensions gives a noticeable performance boost when timing the code, but does it affect the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm?

As I understand, the difference is due to the way comprehensions are evaluated compared to explicit cycles, but this difference should be a constant factor and in that case asymptotic complexity doesn't change and then with the increase in the size of the problem, there should eventually come a point when both versions should perform at the same speed. Is my thinking correct?

At the same time, when I tried to test it, comprehensions have been outperforming explicit cycles all the way until I got to sizes where I as running out of memory.

Comment: Can't you do a few timing tests?  On a simple append from a range, the time ratio between the for loop and the list comprehension remains a nearly constant 2:1.  Both scale linearly, with a drop off in performance for larger problems - probably due to greater memory management complexity.  We see that pattern with `numpy` arrays as well.

Comment: I should add though that for a more complex task (inside the loop) the relative performance of the comprehension is less significant.  The comprehension streamlines the list append, but doesn't change the calculation speed (if any).  If `foo` is simple, `[foo(i) for i in range(n)]`, the iteration mechanism makes a difference.  If `foo` is complex, its evaluation time dominates, regardless of the iteration mechanism.

Comment: List comprehension doesn't give noticeable difference in performance, the reason it could be a little bit faster, in a specific cases when you are appending item into a list, `. append()` method is being avoided, in other words, get rid of function call overhead, and in terms of interpretation and machine code less instructions have been executed, but this doesn't make too much difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question, but that's not how asymptotic complexity works. It's not that they will converge to the same amount of time, it's that they would both grow in the same way. For instance, algorithms that take 2*n and n are of the same asymptotic complexity, but the former will always take two times as long. I can't see any reason why the comprehensions would not have the same complexity, but you can test this empirically with timing tests.